# Search in and across paragraphs

Tags: java, .net, regex, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to develop a function which will highlight the text in a page based on search keywords. I have bounding boxes of all the words in the page and all the words are arranged in ascending order based on its appearance.

Search should support string literal search and also regular expressions.

One option I thought was using tries. Looks like it is good for string literal search and also if the search is to highlight one or more independent words. Handling regular expressions is also not possible here. But once tries are built then it is very efficient as the search time matches with keyword.

Another option would be to concatenate all the words of a page into a single string. Then also index words to their bounding boxes. And then use platform's search function on the big string. This is very simple design but not so efficient. But supports regular expressions also.

Any suggestions on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on how much text and how many keywords. If you're talking one page (a few kilobytes) of text and a handful of keywords, the naive method works well and is plenty fast enough. If you're talking about megabytes of text and lots of keywords, then you want something like the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed by [Jim Mischel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel):

> It really depends on how much text and how many keywords. If you're talking one page (a few kilobytes) of text and a handful of keywords, the naive method works well and is plenty fast enough. If you're talking about megabytes of text and lots of keywords, then you want something like the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)